# Different TabBar Background Colors for Tabs in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I got 3 Tabs and I want different colors for every single Tab in SwiftUI. I know how to do it for the whole app using:

```
init() {
      UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
      UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(named: "blue")
      UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "red")
}
```

Comment: UITabBar does not support background color *per tab item*, so create custom tab bar, it is easy with SwiftUI.

Comment: I will. Maybe this is coming in future...Thank you for the information!